# Choosing a Path for Python File Access

Tags: python, path

One of the features of my project is to allow users to create their own little `.txt` file, put it somewhere on their HDD, which can then be used as criteria for a part of my application.

Is there a Fixed, 'generic'(?) path for *most* OSs that I could use? Or does anyone have any kind of advice or guidance that could help me?

FYI, during development, I've just been using a fixed location (/home/user/Desktop/folder1/"), to which I then specify the filename, in order to complete the path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[os.path.expanduser](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=home#os.path.expanduser) is a good start -- a leading `~/` expands to "the user's home directory", which is computer by reasonable heuristics on both Unix-y and Windows systems.  Of course, you don't want to put your file in the home directly, but a subdirectory of that (which you'll have to make if not already there) is a reasonable default.

Of course, do allow this setting to be overridden by an environment variable or a command line flag passed to your program, because some platforms are rather finicky about where an application is supposed, by convention, to park such auxiliary data files.

**Edit**: the OP asks for an example:

> Suppose I wanted it in ~/tempfoler/
>   and the file being passed to it was
>   args1.txt?

I'd suggest locating the exact path through a function such as:

```
import errno
import os

def getfilepath(filename, foldername='tempfoler', envar='MYAPPDIR'):
  # check for environmental override
  if envar is not None and envar in os.environ:
    dirpath = os.environ[envar]
  else:
    dirpath = '~/%s' % foldername
  # expand and ensure it's a directory
  expanded = os.path.expanduser(dirpath)
  if not os.path.isdir(expanded):
    if os.path.lexists(expanded):
      # we're in dire trouble: the path is a file, not a directory!
      # you could punt to some default value, but I prefer to raise
      # an exception and allow higher levels to deal with this
      raise IOError(errno.EEXISTS, "Path is a file, not a dir", expanded)
    # the following may also raise (permission issues, &c)
    os.makedirs(expanded)
  # now the directory exists, the file may or may not (doesn't matter)
  return os.path.join(expanded, filename)
```

There are some design choices embedded here -- raise exceptions for all kinds of problems (higher levels may catch them and handle them appropriately, e.g. ask the user for an alternative -- this lower level function couldn't do that properly!), return the path to the file which may or may not exist (thus suitable for both reading an existing file or writing a new one), and so on.

You might also choose to do fewer checks and rely more on automatic exceptions being raised for all kinds of anomalies (or vice versa), I just think this one strikes a reasonable balance (and of course it's easy for you to tweak if you prefer a somewhat different approach to such issues). But the key idea is to always focus on what could go wrong and how it will be dealt with (often by higher-level code, the only proper point for possibly asking the user for alternatives) to make your software robust.

Comment: Perfect answer. Though, could I possible have a quick example of how to use this? Suppose I wanted it in `~/tempfoler/` and the file being passed to it was `args1.txt`?

Comment: @_bravado, editing the answer to provide the example you request.

Comment: Hey Alex, can I also ask what this `envar` variable is? i don't understand why it's preset to `MYAPPDIR`?

Comment: @_bravado, envar is an argument with a default value -- where to look in the os environment for a possible override (pass as None when you want no environment variable to override the choice of dirpath). Such flexibility makes it possible to respect a certain platform's particular conventions without necessarily hardcoding them (since the user can override what you do have hardcoded by setting his os environment appropriately).

Answer (score 3):

The [`wx.StandardPaths`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StandardPaths-class.html) module contains methods that return various standard locations in the file system and transparently tries to do "the right thing" under Unix, Mac OS X, and Windows.

Comment: A simple choice if you're using wxpython. I wouldn't want to pull in that huge dependency just to get directory names, especially when there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

For the copy/paste crowd out there...

```
import os
file_obj = open(os.path.expanduser('~/yourapp/file.txt'), 'w')
```

Good luck.